# Java parse json file JSONObject

Tags: java, json, string, parsing

I have json file with such form:

```
{
  "Region_1": {
    "Area_1": {
      "id": "id_1",
      "email": "email_1"
    },
    "Area_2": {
      "id": "id_2",
      "email": "email_2"
    }
  },
  "Region_2": {
      "Area_1": {
      "id": "id_1",
      "email": "email_1"
    },
    "Area_2": {
      "id": "id_2",
      "email": "email_2"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to parse this structure using JSONObject, I have already code which parse this but not get Region_2 only.
Region_1 getting.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(fileData);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : obj.entrySet()) {
        String region = entry.getKey().toString();
        JSONObject areas = new JSONObject(entry.getValue().toString());

        System.out.println("region: " + region);

        List links = areas.entrySet().collect({ it ->
            String area = it.getKey().toString();

            System.out.println("area: " + area);

            JSONObject areaData = new JSONObject(it.getValue().toString());
            String code = areaData.getString("id");
            String email = areaData.getString("email");

            System.out.println("code: " + code.toString());
            System.out.println("email: " + email.toString());
       })
    }
```

Why only first object takes from json file ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!  If you want people to help you should try showing what you've already tried and why it didn't work.  Otherwise it sounds a little like you're asking other people to do your homework for you.

Comment: What is the output you get from the snippet you posted?

Comment: I received something like : Andy : {Smith={email=soc1212@smth.net, id=1212}, John ={email=utiszn1219@smth.net, id=1219}, Veronica={email=1220_vdpzn@smth.net, id=1220}}, need to parse data in scopes and mapping into Map

Comment: Your lines in your question are different than what you say in your comment.  It is important to know which string is id and which is email.

Comment: Sorry on first is email after is id  {email, id}   not correct described in Question

Comment: Had changed file to json but still in problems couse keys is data which i dont know, help to parse